# Slick slider is to high

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Hi i'am trying to make a slick slider with a thumbnail navigation. I am adding the slider items trough javascript, and after that I create the slick sliders. The problem is that the height of the parent  (slider-for && slider-nav) is way to high. Here is my outcome:

[image: image of my outcome]

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="slider-for"></div>
<div class="slider-nav"></div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
var ObjectData = "object": {

        "media": {
            "images": [
                {
                    "type": "bird-image",
                    "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/326900/pexels-photo-326900.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
                },
                {
                    "type": "bird-image",
                    "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/326900/pexels-photo-326900.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
                },
                {
                    "type": "bird-image",
                    "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/326900/pexels-photo-326900.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
                },
                {
                    "type": "bird-image",
                    "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/326900/pexels-photo-326900.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
                },
                {
                    "type": "bird-image",
                    "url": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/326900/pexels-photo-326900.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
                }
            ],
        }
}

function createSlickSlider(){
  $('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});


function appendImages(){
    objectData.media.images.forEach(function(value, index){
       $(".slider-for").append('<div><img class="image-result-top" src="'+objectData.object.media.images[index].url+'"></div>');
    });
    objectData.media.images.forEach(function(value, index){
       $(".slider-nav").append('<div><img class="image-result-bottom" src="'+objectData.object.media.images[index].url+'"></div>');
    });

    createSlickSlider();
}

appendImages();
```

Comment: Can you edit css element, div{width:33.33%} and  div img{width:100%}

Answer (score 0):

Can you please rewrite your js code?

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
  adaptiveHeight: true
});

$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```